# converting an object to an array in angular2 typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an object within an object and i would like to convert the inner one to a string separated comma but it generates an infinite loop

After an observable http request am getting the data this way

```
this._categoryService.getChecklistCategories()
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.categories = res;
      let newitem:string[];
      for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        this.categories.map((category, i) => category.no = i+1);
        var obj = res[i].assigned; //an obect.
        console.log(obj[0]); //get the first index
     }
    })
```

The above console.log(obj[0]) generates

[image]

I would like to create a string of truck_subtype and append it to `this.categories`

I have tried the following

```
     res => {
       this.categories = res;
       let newitem:string[];
       for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
           this.categories.map((category, i) => category.no = i+1);//this adds no i,2,3...
           var obj = res[i].assigned; //array item
            let stringArray: Array<any> = [];  
           for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                  stringArray.push(obj[i].truck_subtype);
                    
            }
             this.categories.map((category, i) => category.assigned= stringArray)                

      }
    }
```

The above generates an infinite loop and fails to add the string of array to `this.categories`

Where am i wrong

Comment: may be the `i` variable that are declared twice (in for and in map()), I think your index never gets to the `res.length` because when you use map you are resigning it.

Answer (score 0):

May be the i variable that are declared four times (in for's and in map's), I think your index never gets to the `res.length` because when you use map you are resigning it.

Try to change the `i`'s inside map to another name like `i2`..., and test it to see if the loops goes away.

```
 res => {
   this.categories = res;
   let newitem:string[];
   for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
       this.categories.map((category, i2) => category.no = i+1);//this adds no i,2,3...
       var obj = res[i].assigned; //array item
        let stringArray: Array<any> = [];  
       for(var i3 =0; i<obj.length; i++){
              stringArray.push(obj[i3].truck_subtype);

        }
         this.categories.map((category, i4) => category.assigned= stringArray)                

  }
}
```